# SharePoint permission levels

Tags: 2010, permissions, groups

How do permission levels work? I don't know why I have "access denied" every time I access a subsite even if I have read permission. I am hopeful that somebody will shed light on this.

Here's the scenario:

Intranet (parent site)
  |- Intranet Owners  (Administrator)
  |- Intranet Members (User1, User2)
  |- Intranet Visitors (GUser1, GUser2)
  |- HR Members (User1) // Contribute permission
  |- Corporate Communications Members (User1,User2) // Contribute permission
  |- IT Members (GUser1, GUser2)  // Contribute permission

Subsites will be the departments:
  |- HR  (default group - HR Members)
  |- Corporate Communications (default group - Corporate Communications Members)
  |- IT (default group - IT Members)

Here's the question:
Can `GUser1` access the Corporate Communications site? `GUser1` has read permission on the site collection level. This is the problem I'm facing right now. I logged in as `GUser1` and got an "Access Denied" error. Why?

Comment: Did you break permission inheritance on the Corp. Communications site?

Comment: I think I did just that. Is this the reason why I got "Access Denied" error? Does the site's permission setting supersedes that of its parent's?

Comment: From remote, it's hard to say what has happen in detail. Does the error persists if you switch inheritance back on?

Comment: Yes I still have the error after switching back the inheritance. But if `GUser1` is added in `Intranet Members` group, `GUser1` can access Corporate Comms' site. If `GUser1` is a member of `Intranet Visitors`, should he be allowed to view the site? That's only read access, I can't understand why `GUser1` is denied access.

Comment: Is it a subsite or site collection, if the departments are sitecollection you may face problems like this in permissions

Comment: Can you check the permissions of that user? Here is written how to do it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/check-permissions-for-a-user-or-group-HA010362860.aspx

Comment: @AlexPoint: The user has read permission and the link is for SharePoint 2007 took me time to find those options in SP2010 though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that GUser1 has Read permission at the site collection level, depending on how the subsite was created, they might not have access to the communications site.  Check the permissions for corporate to ensure the Intranet Visitors group has read permission.  By the way you have spelled it out, it does not appear that Guser1 will have access because he is not listed in the Corp Comm users group and you haven't listed Intranet Visitors as having access to the Corp Comm subsite.

Just because a group as permission at the root of a site, it does not mean that it trckles down to everywhere in the collection.  If subsites are created with custom permissions, then yhe permissions inheritance is broken from it's parent, and any groups that exist at the parent need to be explicitly added to the subsite.

Comment: Ok got it. But if I set a default group for the corporate communications website, call it `CC Members`, the site has unique permissions and explicitly add `GUser1` as user with read permission to the site, still got "Access Denied" error. Why?